# Converter Data para ano / mês

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consegui converter a data para ano / mês, mas necessito que a data saia assim: 2019/04, mas está saindo assim: 2019/4

como posso resolver isso?

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART (year,'01/04/2019')) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(month,'01/04/2019')) as AnoMes
```

Comment: select (convert(varchar(200), year(convert(date, '01/04/2019'))) + '/' + convert(varchar(200), month(convert(date, '01/04/2019')))) as AnoMes

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma:

```
    select format(CAST('04/01/2019' AS DATE), 'yyyy/MM');
```

Esse teste que fiz tive que colocar a data como 'MM/dd/yyyy'.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente

```
-- código #1
SELECT convert (char(7), nome_coluna, 111) as AnoMes
  from tabela;
```

onde *nome_coluna* está declarada como `date`, `datetime` ou algum outro tipo de dados específico para armazenamento de data.
O estilo 111 refere-se ao formato 'aaaa/mm/dd'.

Exemplo:

```
-- código #2
declare @data date;
set @data= convert (date, '1/4/2019', 103);  -- dd/mm/aaaa

SELECT convert (char(7), @data, 111);
```

Answer (score 0):

O SQL fornece algumas conversões prontas de data e hora, aqui tem uma tabelinha:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Conforme o link, poderia estar sendo feito assim:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(7), GETDATE(), 111) AS [ANO/MES]
FROM TABELA
```

O padrão de retorno quando você faz ***CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATA, 111)*** é **'YYYY/MM/dd'**, substituindo **VARCHAR** por **CHAR(7)** ele irá retornar os 7 primeiros caracteres: **'YYYY/MM'**